# How to map trough array of object and toggle boolean property selected

Tags: reactjs

I have state in React functional component. It is and array of objects. Every object in that collection has property "selected", which is a boolean. That array looks like this:

```
const [filterOptions, setFilterOptions] = useState([
        {
            title: 'highest',
            selected: true,
        },
        {
            title: 'lowest',
            selected: false,
        },
    ]);
```

After handleFilter func is executed I need to set state so this array has same title properties but reverse (toggle) selected properties.

This is handleFilter func in which I need to toggle every selected property of array objects:

```
const handleFilter = () => {
        setFilterOptions();
    };
```

Comment: what's the output you want? could not understand from your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function App() {

    const [filterOptions, setFilterOptions] = useState([
        {
            title: 'highest',
            selected: true,
        },
        {
            title: 'lowest',
            selected: false,
        },
    ]);

    const handleFilter = (e) => {
        let newArr = [...filterOptions];

        let value = e.target.value;

        if (value === "lowest") {

            newArr[0].selected = true;
            newArr[1].selected = false;

        } else if (value === "highest") {

            newArr[0].selected = false;
            newArr[1].selected = true;

        } 

        setFilterOptions(newArr)

    };
    return (
        <div>
            <select onChange={handleFilter}>
                <option value="lowest">a</option>
                <option value="highest">b</option>
            </select>
            {console.log((filterOptions))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I dont see how is this solution toggle selected boolean property? I guess you mean !value

Answer (score 0):

please check hope it will work

```js
var arryObj =[
        {
            title: 'highest',
            selected: true,
        },
        {
            title: 'lowest',
            selected: false,
        },
    ]

const handleFilter = (index,value) => {
    arryObj[index].selected = value
    };
handleFilter(0,false)
console.log(arryObj)
handleFilter(1,true)
console.log(arryObj)
```

Comment: But what if I don't know the number of objects in that array? I see here you hardcoded calls to handleFilter with indexes 0 and 1? And this needs to be set into state

Comment: yes hardcode just for example, hope you will use map for rendering this items , so then you can pass map index and item.selected with sign ! like this !item.selected its means is item.selected = true and passing !item.selected like this it will update your Object
example 


filterOptions.map((item,index)=>(
///*UI here and function on click like this  this.handleFilter(index, !item.selected)*////
))

thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function into `setFilterOptions` to change the state based on the previous state.

```
const handleFilter = () => {
    setFilterOptions(prevState => 
        prevState.map(obj => ({...obj, selected: !obj.selected}))
    );
};
```

Comment: For this solution I get eslint error "Declaration or statement expected"

Comment: @Pokreniseweb My bad, I forgot a pair of parentheses hahaha. Fixed it.